# Create fully dynamic where clause with expression tree and execute on IQueryable

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees, iqueryable, where-clause

At point (3) in my code I have defined a query called query1 in which I defined a .Where lambda expression. This query is in some way dynamic but still contains static elements, it always refers to the Type Employee and its (int) property ClientID.

Now I very much like to make the refering to the type and its property dynamic, based on the method parameters which by example are shown below point (1).

What I tried to so far is making the static part of the query defined under point (3) fully dynamic by replacing it with a more elaborate expression tree as written down in (4), (5) & (6). But when I try to add everything together it says I call .Where with wrong parameters. I don't know how to call .Where with the right parameters in order to create a fully dynamic select.

Does someone know to solve this problem? I have spent a day searching and haven't found a solution so far.

```
        dsMain domainService = new dsMain();


        //(1)i want to rewrite the following four variables to method-parameters
        Type entityType = typeof(Employee);
        String targetProperty = "ClientID";
        Type entityProperty = typeof(Employee).GetProperty(targetProperty).PropertyType;
        int idToDelete = 5;


        //(2)create expression-function: idToDelete == entityType.targetProperty (in this case: Employee.ClientID)
        ParameterExpression numParam = Expression.Parameter(entityProperty, targetProperty.Substring(0, 3));
        ConstantExpression equalTarget = Expression.Constant(idToDelete, idToDelete.GetType());
        BinaryExpression intEqualsID = Expression.Equal(numParam, equalTarget);
        Expression<Func<int, bool>> lambda1 =
                    Expression.Lambda<Func<int, bool>>(
                    intEqualsID,
                    new ParameterExpression[] { numParam });

        //(3)I want to create query1 fully dynamic, so defining Employee or an other type and its property at run time
        WhereClause = lambda1.Compile();
        IQueryable<Employee> employees = domainService.GetEmployees();
        var query1 = employees.Where<Employee>(C => WhereClause.Invoke(C.ClientID)).Expression;



        //(4)create the operand body {value(ASP.test_aspx).WhereClause.Invoke(E.ClientID)}
        var operandbodyMethod = WhereClause.GetType().GetMethod("Invoke");
        var operandbodyType = typeof(System.Boolean);
        var operandbodyArgs1Expression = Expression.Parameter(entityType, entityType.Name.Substring(0, 1));
        var operandbodyArgs1 = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(operandbodyArgs1Expression, entityType.GetMember(targetProperty)[0]);
        var operandBodyObjectExp = Expression.Constant(this, this.GetType());
        var operandbodyObject = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(operandBodyObjectExp, this.GetType().GetMember("WhereClause")[0]);

        //(5)create the operand {E => value(ASP.test_aspx).WhereClause.Invoke(E.ClientID)}
        var operandbody = Expression.Call(operandbodyObject, operandbodyMethod, operandbodyArgs1);
        var operandParameter = Expression.Parameter(entityType, entityType.Name.Substring(0, 1));
        var operandType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(entityType, typeof(System.Boolean));

        //(6)
        var operand = Expression.Lambda(operandType, operandbody, new ParameterExpression[] { operandParameter });
        var expressionType = typeof(Expression<>).MakeGenericType(operandType);
        var completeWhereExpression = Expression.MakeUnary(ExpressionType.Quote, operand, expressionType);


        //(7)the line below does not work
        var query2 = employees.Where<Employee>(completeWhereExpression).Expression;
```

Thank you very much for reading my question!
If you have questions about my question, please ask them:)

Comment: No matter what you create with expression trees, you will still need to have an IQueryable to operate upon.  In your example, what is domainService?  Looks like some sort of data context, but not LinqToSql's.  You have a method, GetEmployees() on it, does domainService offer any mechanism to get the IQueryable based on a System.Type, like LinqToSql's does?

Comment: domainService extends LinqToEntitiesDomainService<dbUbiHorecaEntities> (http://bit.ly/dr8Zkd), it is part of the WCF RIA Services framework(http://bit.ly/aHusJT). domainService has specific CRUD methods for each entity in my EDM called dbUbiHorecaEntities. It has no special mechanism to get IQueryables based on System.Type, however, its possible with reflection: each entity X has a get method in domainService called getX(), returning an IQueryable<X>. Example: IQueryable<X> = domainService.GetType().GetMethod("Get" + X.getType().GetName()).Invoke(domainService , null). Is this of help for you?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is quite hard to look at in isolation, but the first thing that occurs is that `Compile` looks out of place for `IQueryable` - that will *rarely* work (LINQ-to-Objects being the exception).

An equivalent to `WhereClause.Invoke(C.ClientID)` is to use `Expression.Invoke` to call a sub-expression, but even this is flakey: LINQ-to-SQL will support it, EF (in 3.5 at least) doesn't (maybe "didn't"; I haven't re-checked in 4.0). Ultimately, it would be more robust to create `lambda1` as an `Expression<Func<Employee,bool>>` if possible:

```
    ParameterExpression empParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Employee),"emp");
    ConstantExpression equalTarget = Expression.Constant(idToDelete, idToDelete.GetType());
    BinaryExpression intEqualsID = Expression.Equal(
        Expression.PropertyOrField(empParam, targetProperty), equalTarget);
    Expression<Func<Exmployee, bool>> lambda1 =
                Expression.Lambda<Func<int, bool>>(
                intEqualsID,
                empParam);
```

Then pass *this* to `Where`:

```
var query1 = employees.Where(lambda1);
```

Comment: Thank you Marc! It worked! And so little code. (Btw, it is possible in EF 4.0:)) (also thank you Kirk for you effort:))