# Are Linq-To-Sql Dynamic-Where-Clauses Even Possible in Framework 3.5?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, .net-3.5, where-clause

**UPDATE: It Is Now Working**
I was able to finally get it completed.  A working-example is detailed in an answer below (which I will be able to mark-off in 2 days).

---

### **Everything Below Here Was Part of the Original Question**

For the last 3 days, I have been trying to build a dynamic-where-clause on a [**DBML DataContext**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399400.aspx) using code samples from [**questions posted here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8140851/creating-a-dynamic-where-clause-as-a-linq-expression/8140907#8140907) and from [**other sources**](http://pastebin.com/feb8cc1e) as well...***none have worked***!

For the reasons below, I am beginning to wonder if this is even POSSIBLE using under Framework 3.5:

1. [**Predicate Builder**](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) notes Framework 4.0 on their site.
2. Some [**answers here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444457/create-fully-dynamic-where-clause-with-expression-tree-and-execute-on-iqueryable) talk about an equivolent `Invoke` versions in 4.0 (so I have *some* hope here).
3. ...I could go on but you get the idea.

I am really at a loss and seem to be "grabbing at strings"...and I need some sound advice on how to approach this.

**Original Version Had [SOME Success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8140851/creating-a-dynamic-where-clause-as-a-linq-expression/8140907#8140907) But Only When:**
The ONLY time I had a 'inkling' of success the data came-up (all 6178 rows of it) but no `WHERE CLAUSE` was applied.  This was evidenced by the **lack** of any `WHERE CLAUSE` applied into the `SQL` found in the `dataContext.GetCommand(query).CommandText`.

**Other Version #1 Fails:**
And generates this error: "Method 'System.Object DynamicInvoke(System.Object[])' has no supported translation to SQL."

```
// VERSION 1:
public static class PredicateBuilder
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> True<T>() { return f => true; }
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> False<T>() { return f => false; }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1, Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
    {
        var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression>());
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.OrElse(expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
    }
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1, Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
    {
        var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression>());
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.AndAlso(expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
    }
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> StringLike<T>(Expression<Func<T, string>> selector, string pattern)
    {
        var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<T>();
        var parts = pattern.Split('%');
        if (parts.Length == 1) // not '%' sign
        {
            predicate = predicate.And(s => selector.Compile()(s) == pattern);
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
            {
                string p = parts[i];
                if (p.Length > 0)
                {
                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                        predicate = predicate.And(s => selector.Compile()(s).StartsWith(p));
                    }
                    else if (i == parts.Length - 1)
                    {
                        predicate = predicate.And(s => selector.Compile()(s).EndsWith(p));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        predicate = predicate.And(s => selector.Compile()(s).Contains(p));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return predicate;
    }
}
// VERSION 1:
public List<QuickFindResult> QueryDocuments(string searchText, string customerSiteId, List<int> filterIds)
{
    var where = PredicateBuilder.True<vw_QuickFindResult>();

    var searches = new List<String>(searchText.Split(' '));
    searches.ForEach(productName =>
    {
        string like = productName.Replace('"', '%')
                                 .Replace('*', '%');

        where = PredicateBuilder.StringLike<vw_QuickFindResult>(x => x.DocumentName, like);
    });


    var results = DocumentCollectionService.ListQuickFind(where, null);

    // Do other stuff here...

    return results;
}
// VERSION 1:
public static List<vw_QuickFindResult> ListQuickFind(Expression<Func<vw_QuickFindResult, bool>> where, Expression<Func<vw_QuickFindResult, bool>> orderBy)
{
    var connectionString = GetConnectionString(ES_DOCUMENTS_CONNECTION_NAME);
    List<vw_QuickFindResult> results = null;

    using (HostingEnvironment.Impersonate())
    {
        using (var dataContext = new ES_DocumentsDataContext(connectionString))
        {
            IQueryable<vw_QuickFindResult> query = dataContext.vw_QuickFindResults;
            query = query.Where(where);

            results = query.ToList();
        }
    }

    return results;
}
```

**Other Version #2 Fails:**
And generates this error: "Method 'Boolean Like(System.String, System.String)' cannot be used on the client; it is only for translation to SQL."

```
// VERSION 2:
public List<QuickFindResult> QueryDocuments(string searchText, string customerSiteId, List<int> filterIds)
{
    Func<vw_QuickFindResult, bool> where = null;
    Func<string, Func<vw_QuickFindResult, bool>> buildKeywordPredicate = like => x => SqlMethods.Like(x.DocumentName, like);
    Func<Func<vw_QuickFindResult, bool>, Func<vw_QuickFindResult, bool>, Func<vw_QuickFindResult, bool>> buildOrPredicate = (pred1, pred2) => x => pred1(x) || pred2(x);

    // Build LIKE Clause for the WHERE
    var searches = new List<String>(searchText.Split(' '));
    searches.ForEach(productName =>
    {
        string like = productName.Replace('"', '%')
                                 .Replace('*', '%');

        where = (where == null) ? buildKeywordPredicate(like) : buildOrPredicate(where, buildKeywordPredicate(like));
    });

    var results = DocumentCollectionService.ListQuickFind(where, null);

    // Do other stuff here...

    return results;
}
// VERSION 2:
public static List<vw_QuickFindResult> ListQuickFind(Expression<Func<vw_QuickFindResult, bool>> where, Expression<Func<vw_QuickFindResult, bool>> orderBy)
{
    var connectionString = GetConnectionString(ES_DOCUMENTS_CONNECTION_NAME);
    List<vw_QuickFindResult> results = null;

    using (HostingEnvironment.Impersonate())
    {
        using (var dataContext = new ES_DocumentsDataContext(connectionString))
        {
            var query = dataContext.vw_QuickFindResults.AsEnumerable();
            query = query.Where(where);

            results = query.ToList();
        }
    }

    return results;
}
```

Comment: I have updated the question with a working sample

Comment: It's good you found the answer yourself. Probably the best approach would have been to have added an answer yourself with all the corrections included in it so the question is clear.

Comment: Great question. Glad you got it working. I started working with predicate builder a while back and remember the growing pains. When you said... "I don't know why" was that referencing why you needed to use .False<> instead of .True<>? If so... Those methods start off your predicate with a base value of either true or false. If you start with True and then build your predicate with OR it will always evaluate back to true because TRUE OR anything=True. also if you start with False and try to AND to your predicate it will always eval to false. Ignore me if I misunderstood your confusion :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**THIS IS THE CORRECT ASWER**
Here is the working version for those who need it.  The issue was a COMBINATION of things.  The first of which was the following line was set to `True`:

`var where = PredicateBuilder.True<vw_QuickFindResult>();`

It should be `False`...

`var where = PredicateBuilder.False<vw_QuickFindResult>();`

I don't know why...but other changes were needed also.

```
public static class PredicateBuilder
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> True<T>() { return f => true; }
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> False<T>() { return f => false; }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1, Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
    {
        var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression>());
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.OrElse(expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
    }
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1, Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
    {
        var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression>());
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.AndAlso(expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
    }
}
public List<QuickFindResult> QueryDocuments(string searchText, string customerSiteId, List<int> filterIds)
{
    var wildCards = new string[] { "*", "\"" };
    var where = PredicateBuilder.False<vw_QuickFindResult>();
    var searches = new List<String>(searchText.Split(' ')); // TODO: <-- If more complex searches are needed we'll have to use RegularExpressions

    // SEARCH TEXT - WHERE Clause
    searches.ForEach(productName =>
    {
        Boolean hasWildCards = (productName.IndexOfAny(new char[] { '"', '*' }) != -1);
        if (hasWildCards)
        {
            Int32 length = productName.Length;
            if (length > 1)
            {
                string like = productName.Replace("%", "")
                                         .Replace("*", "");

                string first = productName.Substring(0, 1);
                string last = productName.Substring(length - 1);

                // Contains
                if (wildCards.Contains(first) && wildCards.Contains(last))
                    where = where.Or(p => p.DocumentName.Contains(like) ||
                                         p.DocumentTitle.Contains(like));

                // EndsWith
                else if (wildCards.Contains(first))
                    where = where.Or(p => p.DocumentName.EndsWith(like) ||
                                          p.DocumentTitle.EndsWith(like));

                // StartsWith
                else if (wildCards.Contains(last))
                    where = where.Or(p => p.DocumentName.StartsWith(like) ||
                                          p.DocumentTitle.StartsWith(like));

                // Contains (default)
                else
                    where = where.Or(p => p.DocumentName.Contains(like) ||
                                          p.DocumentTitle.Contains(like));
            }
            else // Can only perform a "contains"
                where = where.Or(p => p.DocumentName.Contains(productName) ||
                                             p.DocumentTitle.Contains(productName));
        }
        else // Can only perform a "contains"
            where = where.Or(p => p.DocumentName.Contains(productName) ||
                                         p.DocumentTitle.Contains(productName));
    });

    // FILTER IDS - WHERE Clause
    var filters = GetAllFilters().Where(x => filterIds.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();
    filters.ForEach(filter =>
    {
        if (!filter.IsSection)
            where = where.And(x => x.FilterName == filter.Name);
    });

    var dataSource = DocumentCollectionService.ListQuickFind(where);
    var collection = new List<QuickFindResult>();

    // Other UNRELATED stuff happens here...

    return collection;
}
public static List<vw_QuickFindResult> ListQuickFind(Expression<Func<vw_QuickFindResult, bool>> where)
{
    var connectionString = GetConnectionString(ES_DOCUMENTS_CONNECTION_NAME);
    List<vw_QuickFindResult> results = null;

    using (HostingEnvironment.Impersonate())
    {
        using (var dataContext = new ES_DocumentsDataContext(connectionString))
        {
            var query = dataContext.vw_QuickFindResults.Where(where).OrderBy(x => x.DocumentName).OrderBy(x => x.DocumentTitle);
            results = query.ToList();
        }
    }

    return results;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try building the query yourself using only Exression classes?
There should be no particular problems there. It is actually relatively easy to learn.
You can write a sample query, and then in debugging see how it is composed:

```
Expression<Func<string, bool>> exp = (s) => s.Contains("your query");
```

Then simply look at the exp variable in the watch, and you can see the structure.
This particular example should be composed like this:

```
Expression constant = Expression.Constant("your query");
Expression p = Expression.Param(typeof(string);
Expression contains = Expression.Call(p, "Contains", constant);
Expression<Func<string, bool>> lambda = Expression.Lamba(contains, p);
//  Now you can send this to your ORM
```

Comment: ORM?  I'm not using EntityFramework.  Does the above example work with the 'dataContext' listed above?

Comment: Why shouldn't it work? You use Expression in your code to create predicates. But for some reason, you try to use thirdparty libraries, which don't seem to make life easier for you. Just try to create Expression with what you got in .Net. In my example I tried to create a predicate similar to what you wanted (with like '%keyword%')

Comment: Vlad, I kinda like where you're going, but this didn't compile and I'm not really sure where to go with it.

Answer (score 0):

For what I can tell you, I have used LinqKit and PredicateBuilder back in early 2010 with .Net 3.5, EF 1.0 and EF Poco Adapter. Back then, LinqKit was compiled for Net 3.5

Maybe if you ask the author (Albahari), he could send you (or post on the site) the 3.5 version of that. I don't have it anymore because it is in projects at my old workplace and I don't have access to them.

As a side note, I feel your pain being forced to work with 3.5 after almost 2 years of .Net 4 being around.